# Boost Order Information System

Tags: codeigniter

i'm try to get `news_id` from database but when go to view say this error :

> Trying to get property of non-object / Message: Message: Undefined variable: xls

model:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed'); class Mdl_tagihan extends CI_Model { public function employeeList() {
        $this->db->select(array('e.id', 'e.IDTAGIHAN', 'e.BANDWIDTH_BILLING', 'e.SITE_NAME', 'e.PERIODE_TAGIHAN', 
        'e.REGION', 'e.NOMINAL', 'e.USED_FOR','e.RECON_PERIOD','e.OA_DATE','e.REQUEST_ID','e.TRANSMISSION_ID','e.PROVIDER','e.PRODUCT',
        'e.SOW', 'e.NE_ID', 'e.NE_NAME', 'e.FE_ID', 'e.FE_NAME', 'e.BANDWIDTH', 'e.SERVICE_2G', 'e.SERVICE_3G', 'e.SERVICE_4G', 'e.TOTAL_SERVICE'));
        $this->db->from('import as e');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

controller:

```
class Ctrl_tagihan extends CI_Controller { public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    if($this->session->userdata('group') != '1'){
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Maaf, login first!');
        redirect('CTRL_Login');
    }

    $this->load->model('Mdl_tagihan');
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->library('upload');
}

public function index()
{
    $data['tagihan'] = $this->Mdl_tagihan->get_tagihan();
    $this->load->view('admin/dbtagihan/index_tagihan', $data);
}


public function export_excel(){
    $data = array( 'IDTAGIHAN' => 'Laporan Excel',
    'dbtagihan' => $this->Mdl_tagihan->listing());
    $this->load->view('admin/dbtagihan/laporanexcel_tagihan',$data);
}
```

view:

```
 <?php ("Content-type: application/octet-stream"); header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$xls.xls.xls"); ("Pragma: no-cache"); ("Expires: 0") ?> <table border="1" width="100%"> <thead> <tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the `$xls` on your view, you have to supply a `$xls` variable on the controller :

```php
public function export_excel(){
    $data = array( 'IDTAGIHAN' => 'Laporan Excel',
    'dbtagihan' => $this->Mdl_tagihan->listing());
    $data['xls'] = 'Title';
    $this->load->view('admin/dbtagihan/laporanexcel_tagihan',$data);
}
```